# Text Box For Blogger

Tags: html, css, blogger

I want Text Box for my blogger in which i can post Html - CSS codes and user's can copy them.
Example = http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OhvKmLgY-O4/UnaA9HGfcVI/AAAAAAAAA3Y/b4VrxT8BK8U/s1600/Long+code.png

My Image Link = http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-i3AX6FFu9N8/UnYbGgMgYhI/AAAAAAAAA2k/SFv0kK7x6YI/s1600/Coding+Place+For+Blogger.png

I want that If the code is small. It should automatically become like this = http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-RYmQ9CRKiVw/UnaAv0niNuI/AAAAAAAAA3Q/2Fi6bRvkUUg/s1600/small+code.png

and If the code is long, it should automatically be like this = http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-OhvKmLgY-O4/UnaA9HGfcVI/AAAAAAAAA3Y/b4VrxT8BK8U/s1600/Long+code.png

When i try to make it and i paste the code in it, it become horrible, you can see = http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-CP8_CBwHwMk/UnZ33pJdhEI/AAAAAAAAA2w/8e8mZUsAwRo/s1600/solution+please.png

CSS CODE:

```
#tbox1 {
    background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-i3AX6FFu9N8/UnYbGgMgYhI/AAAAAAAAA2k/SFv0kK7x6YI/s1600/Coding+Place+For+Blogger.png) no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:380px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:20px 40px;
    overflow:auto;
    word-wrap:nowrap;
    /*font styles*/
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    /*1em*/
    color:#000000;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="tbox1">Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code Testing The Code v</div>
```

You can see on JsFiddle that what's actually happening to me

http://jsfiddle.net/e5nHr/

Comment: Is the image URL in the css correct? For me it says 404.

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/H7569/). Though I did add `no-repeat` to the background property.

Comment: @havana Yea That time, image url was not correct. but i correct it, Check my new problem :| . I've posted an answer here

Comment: @BramVanroy Yea no-repeat works fine , Thanks! Check new question. (i've posted in answer )

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your css:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

I also noticed that image you are supplying has some design on left border so you need to also supply some padding

```
padding-left: 60px;
padding-top: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/H7569/

```
 #tbox1 {
     background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-i3AX6FFu9N8/UnYbGgMgYhI/AAAAAAAAA2k/SFv0kK7x6YI/s1600/Coding+Place+For+Blogger.png) no-repeat center center;
     width:500px;
     height:333px;
     margin:10px;
     /*font styles*/
     font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     font-size:16px;
     /*1em*/
     color:#000000;
     line-height:20px;
 }
 .content {
     width: 410px;
     height: 290px;
     overflow: auto;
     position: relative;
     top: 20px;
     left: 60px;
     bottom: 20px;
     right: 20px;
 }
```